# A potential well with 3-fold reflection symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, parity, lattice-model, tight-binding, bloch-sphere

When we are talking about Bloch's theorem and also the tight-binding approximation, we can use them to help finding eigenstates of a system. However, I am so confused how to apply it in this case (below is my homework) and don't even know how to start it......

All I understand about the Bloch's theorem is that we can find a wavefunction that is a product of plane wave and a periodic function. (i.e $\psi(r)=e^{ikr}u(r)$)

This will be great if someone can discuss it with me and direct my thinking......This may be a silly question but I am really lost here... I am not asking for direct answer but I really need a hand on this, so a solid discussion would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Find the eigenstate]
[image: Potential well figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflections $P$, $P'$ and $P''$ do not commute. Hence, there is no general basis of eigenvectors for these transformations. Consider the transformation $R_{2\pi/3} = P P'$, which is a clockwise rotation by an angle of $2\pi/3$. In this problem, the rotations by the angles $2\pi/3$ and $4\pi/3$ are analogs of the lattice translations. Since $(R_{2\pi/3})^3$ is an identity transformation, it is quite obvious that the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $H$ are
$$
|k\rangle = |0\rangle + e^{ik}|1\rangle + e^{i2k}|2\rangle,\quad k = 0, 2\pi/3, 4\pi/3
$$
The state $|k=0\rangle$ is invariant under all reflections. The states $|k=2\pi/3\rangle$ and $|k=4\pi/3\rangle$ are transformed into each other by reflections. Hence, these states must have the same energy. One can easily construct the eigenstates of any of the reflections from the $|k\rangle$ states.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I have been digging in what you have said above and I "think" I get it....yes, if I put it in a matrix form and I get 2 eigenvalues with one of them have degeneracies. However, can we say that these 2 eigenstates are the eigenstates of Hamiltonian and also the Parity operator?

Comment: What is a Parity operator? If you mean transformation $\bf{r} \to -\bf{r}$, it is not a symmetry of the Hamiltonian in this case. If you choose one of the reflections as the parity operator, you can construct the corresponding eigenstates from $|k\rangle$ states. For example, eigenstates of the Hamiltonian and of the reflection $P$ are $|k=0\rangle$, $|k=2\pi/3\rangle + |k=4\pi/3\rangle$ and $|k=2\pi/3\rangle - |k=4\pi/3\rangle$